# How to add routes for backend admin layout in UI router

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am looking for solution in angular js UI Router. I am developing an app in angular js and I designed its routes with ui-router. 
I want to know, how to run two separate templates in angular. Suppose I have user and admin two different section.
The Template design of user section is as below
[image]

And I want to access this user section with `localhost:3000/#/`

Now, I have admin section which has different layout design as below
[image]

and I want to access this layout with `locahost:3000/#/admin`.

In ui-router we can put `<ui-view>` tag in only one index.html.
Please help me how  can I run above layouts in same angular app and tell me file structure and code to achieve this.

Thanks...

Comment: I am not getting understood code of suggested link. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to implement as per your UX but it does have room for improvement.

http://embed.plnkr.co/Sgk6wPb12gU4YhAKZCOk/